# Incorrect dimensions returned for VideoJS?

Tags: video.js

I did some sample code like this:

```
this.on('timeupdate', function() {
  console.log(video.videoHeight());
});
```

As the video plays, the height actively changes at random points. Meanwhile if I just do a console.log of `video.videoWidth()` it gives me a width that is clearly too narrow vs what I am viewing. Not sure what is wrong here at all, or how to attempt to debug because it's such a basic command.

Comment: Did you try `this.currentHeight()`?

Comment: https://docs.videojs.com/docs/api/player.html doesn't show that , but https://docs.videojs.com/player#currentWidth does. Hopping around projects at work so I'll verify this is fix tomorrow probably :)

Comment: The first doc you linked is deprecated.